# NeDB database is not loading

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, nedb

Can you explain the reasons of error while loading database&

Here is a code of an electron application

```
function startDB(_win, _path) {
    const db = {};

    const dictStructureList = [
        ...dict_models_1.dictsFromMedApiList,
    ];

    [...driver_channels_interface_1.channelNamesOnly, ...dictStructureList, { name: 'dictVersions' }].forEach(channel => {
        db[channel.name] = new Datastore({ filename: _path + '\/nedb\/' + channel.name, autoload: true });
    });

    initChannels(_win, db, [...driver_channels_interface_1.channelNamesOnly, ...dictStructureList, { name: 'dictVersions' }]);
}
```

When initializing database I recieve error "EFAULT: bad address in system call argument, write"

Can you help me to solve this problem?